# what is eigenvalue of $P^{1/n}$ operator if we know eigenvalue equation of $P$ ?

Tags: eigenvalue

If $P$ is an operator and $PΨ=pΨ$ ( $p$ as the eigenvalue ) then is it true to say $P^{1/n}Ψ=p^{1/n}Ψ$ ( n is an integer and positive number )

Comment: Look at the operator in the eigenbasis;  ie, diagonalize it.

Comment: Please don't post the same question [twice](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234475/find-eigenvalue-for-some-fractional-power-of-operator#comment511767_234475).

Comment: To close reviewers: the proposed duplicate is closed as a duplicate of this one...

Comment: You need to *define* $P^{1/n}$ first. Defining it will immediately answer your question.

Comment: Wt you mean of define? Its clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the operator $P^{1/n}$ is relatively hard to define: we have sort of the same problems we have with complex numbers (there are in general multiple $n$th roots of any nonzero $z\in\mathbb C$) except that we have them separately on every dimension, which sort of mostly kills the whole thing.

However, if $P$ is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices), and self-adjoint, then there are good chances that it will have a unique self-adjoint positive semidefinite $n$th root. Such an operator $Q$ is then characterized by

- having all-nonnegative eigenvalues, and
- $Q^n\psi=P\psi$ for all $\psi$.

If $P$ has a discrete eigenbasis $\{\psi_k\}$ with eigenvalues $\{p_k\}$, then the operator $Q$ such that
$$Q\psi_k=p_k^{1/n}\psi_k  \tag{$\ast$} $$
obviously satisfies these criteria, and therefore that's the operator you want. In general, it's very hard for an operator that doesn't satisfy $(\ast)$ to make any sense as an $n$th root of $P$ (although I can't discount some pathological case outright) and generally you can always assume such a relationship.

Comment: $Q\psi_k = p_k^{1/n}\psi_k \implies Q^n \psi_k = p_k \psi_k = P \psi_k$ and since $\{\psi_k\}$ is a basis $Q^n=P$. The interesting question (in my opinion) is however whether such $Q$ exists even though $P$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @gonenc If $P$ is not diagonalizable, then it is not self-adjoint, but this could be due to a number of reasons and the question is not particularly well-defined unless you specify the situation. If the diagonalizability breaks because of $P$ having a continuous spectrum it's one thing; if it breaks because $P$ is not symmetric, or even [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), then that's another kettle of fish. So it is indeed an interesting cluster of questions - just not a single well-defined one.

Comment: Say an example of this type, plz

Comment: @asaa The simplest example of a defective matrix is a Jordan block such as $$M=\begin{pmatrix}p&1\\ 0&p\end{pmatrix},$$ for which an $n$th root is $$N=\begin{pmatrix}p^{1/n}&p^{-1+1/n}/n\\ 0&p^{1/n}\end{pmatrix},$$ but for which neither $M$ nor $N$ is either self-adjoint or diagonalizable. $M$ is missing an eigenvector for its multiplicity-two eigenvalue, so you simply can't build $N$ through a diagonalization procedure.

Comment: On the other hand, it is always the case that if $Q$ has an eigenvector $\psi$ with eigenvalue $p^{1/n}$, then $\psi$ will also be an eigenvector of $Q^n$ with eigenvalue $p$.